how to communicate (read and create) data with a mikrotik router from his hotspot?
I'm trying to read user profile(i created it) and create user in my router mikrotik from his hostpot. When i use fetch to read profil it return error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Below, my request to read user profile
 const url= "https://192.168.88.1:8383/rest/ip/hotspot/user/profile";
fetch(url,{
    method:'GET',
    headers:{
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' +btoa('routerusername:routerpassword'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).

That is correct way to communicate?
